# Fully Server Component vs Hybrid Component for UI styling / Nextjs-Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm newbie and I wonder which one of the faster than the other or is there any dramatic difference between them ?

**>Server Component with fully rendered ui using Tailwind css**

**>Server component for fetching and use Client component for ui using Chakra UI**